# Html form data to pdf-Html tags get missing

Tags: php, fpdf

I have form when i submit form post values should convert to pdf usinf fpdf

My function

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$html = '<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td width="150" height="30">Company Name: </td>
        <td width="200" height="30"> ' . $_POST['c_name'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="150" height="30">Country: </td>
            <td width="200" height="30"> ' . $_POST['Country'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="150" height="30">Contact person:</td>
            <td width="200" height="30"> ' . $_POST['Contact_Person'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="150" height="30">Email id:</td>
            <td width="200" height="30"> ' . $_POST['emailid'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="150" height="30">Phone number:</td>
            <td width="200" height="30"> ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</td>
    </tr>

</table>';

echo $html;
exit;
```

Convert page:

```
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$rand = mt_rand();
```

When i echo my table i got
[image: MY form]

Form is convert to pdf but html tags get missed.i didnt get expected output
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you check the post data?

Comment: You only echo the HTML in `$html` If you want to send the PDF to the user, you have to complete the PDF file first and then send it

Comment: Also remember, the first time a page loads, it has not been submitted and therefore the `$_POST` variables have not been set

Comment: Is this ALL the code in that script?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have convert form to pdf but expected table didnt get..table gets disorted